# JavaMail: get size of a MimeMessage

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to get the size of a MimeMessage.
The method getSize() simply always returns -1.

This is my code:

```
MimeMessage m = new MimeMessage(session);
m.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress, true));
m.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toAddress, true));
m.setSubject(subject);

MimeBodyPart bodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
bodyPart.setContent(body, "text/html");
Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
mp.addBodyPart(bodyPart);
m.setContent(mp);

m.getSize(); // -1 is returned
```

**THIS IS THE ANSWER TO MY QUESTION:**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
m.writeTo(os);
int bytes = os.size();
```

Answer (score 3):

A more efficient solution, but requiring an external library, is the following one:

```
public static long getReliableSize(MimeMessage m) throws IOException, MessagingException {
    try (CountingOutputStream out = new CountingOutputStream(new NullOutputStream())) {
        m.writeTo(out);
        return out.getByteCount();
    }
}
```

Both CountingOutputStream and NullOutputStream are available in Apache Common IO. That solution doesn't require to work with a temporary byte buffer (write, allocate, re-allocate, etc.)

Comment: I see a huge difference in bytes count returned from apache lib when I compare it to Java mime message.getSize() output. any insight on this?

Answer (score 3):

Solution provided with Apache Commons is good, but NullOutputStream() constructor is now deprecated. Use the singleton instead:

```java
CountingOutputStream out = new CountingOutputStream(NullOutputStream.NULL_OUTPUT_STREAM);
```

Answer (score 1):

try calling mp.getSize() to see what it returns, MIMEMessage calls it on mp only.
Also From MIME message API

> Return the size of the content of
>   this part in bytes. Return -1 if the
>   size cannot be determined.

As of now you have not passed any contents to the message,that could be the reason on -1 return value.

Comment: What do you mean that I have not passed any contents? I executed m.setContent(mp)

Comment: bodyPart.getSize() returns -1

Comment: add some contents to the body.. should get the approx size after that.

Comment: If anyone is still looking at this, MimeMessage and MimeBodyPart run getSize() on the content object or content stream. These are set by the constructors, but not by setContent(), so even if getContent() returns data, getSize() will wrongly return -1. Use a debugger to track down the internal data, since it can be stored in several places under the datahandler. For example, attachments can be measured by calling available() on the datahandler's datasource's input stream.